# How can I force rails to recognize a method's location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-plugins, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm having trouble in my application where a controller is calling a method and the server is reporting that the method doesn't exist.

This is the method call. The method not working is tag.related_tags

```
@related_tags = @tags.collect { |tag| tag.related_tags }.flatten.uniq
```

The Tag model is originally defined in an plugin acts-as-taggable-on. It is then extended inside of the plugin that contains it, community_engine. Then finally it is extended again in my app directory. The method related_tags is located inside of the community_engine plugin's tag.rb file.

Edits:
Here is the error message

```
undefined method `related_tags' for #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 26, name: "sql">
```

And the stack trace

```
c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:260:in `method_missing'
c:/Users/Teddy/railCode/careercup/app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:80:in `show'
c:/Users/Teddy/railCode/careercup/app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:80:in `collect'
c:/Users/Teddy/railCode/careercup/app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:80:in `show'
```

Comment: Can you paste a stack trace showing the missing method exception? It could be that `@tags` is composed of Array objects, not Tag objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code of the two plugins you mention I don't think the model hierarchy works how you expect.  The CommunityEngine Tag model does not extend `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag`.  So, the Tag objects you're working with do not have a `related_tags` method defined.

Comment: Inside of the CommunityEngine Tag I put `require_dependency File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../plugins/acts_as_taggable_on/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/tag.rb'`
I'm also using the plugin desert which if I understand correctly, takes care of extending the models.